# Having private pictures in your Android app, which path is correct?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, filesystems

I am making an app where a user can take pictures, but I don't want them to be directly accessible outside the app. The user can choose to send a picture somewhere else if they want, but by default the pictures should be internal to the app only.

What is the correct way to do this? There are so many different path defaults in Android and I am not sure which I should be using (internal memory, external memory, internal cache, external cache, SD Cards, etc).

I am looking at this link here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

It looks like internal storage via `getFilesDir()` is what I am looking for, correct? However pictures are also large files and I don't know if it makes sense to put them internal to the phone or if this is bad practice.

Comment: Yes, You can save it to your app folder `/data/data/package_name/...`. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30481706/4316327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Forget the Storage Permission talk](https://youtu.be/C28pvd2plBA?t=147), `getFilesDir()` is indeed the right location for private storage of user data.